# php scanning content for specific keywords

Tags: php, search, tags, keyword

As part of a CMS admin, I would like to scan new articles for specific keyphrases/tags that are stored in a mysql db.

I am proficient enough to be able to pull the list of keywords out, loop through them and do stripos, and substr_count to build an array of the found keywords. but the average article is about 700 words and there are 16,000 tags and growing so currently the loop takes about 0.5s which was longer than I had hoped, and will only ever get longer.

Is there a better way of doing this? Even if this type of procedure has a special name, that could help.

I have PHP 5.3 on Fedora, it is also on dedicated servers so I don't have any shared host issues.

EDIT - I am such a scatterbrain, I swore blind that I copy and pasted some code! clearly not

```
$found = array();
while($row = $pointer->fetch_assoc())
{
    if(stripos($haystack, $row["Name"]) )
    {
        $found[$row["Name"]] = substr_count( $haystack, $row["Name"]);
    }
}
arsort($found);
```

I think I explained myself badly, because I want to do the procedure on new articles they are currently not in the database, so I was just going to use $_POST in an ajax request, rather than saving the article to the DB first.

Comment: Fulltext search and/or sphinxsearch

Comment: apologies I didn't see you there! see comments below :)

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html is exactly what you are looking for if you don't want to use a search engine script such as sphinx/solr.

Comment: Apologies I wasn't clear enough, see edit, and as the article is just in memory/$_POST I am only running one db query to get the keywords, one query search per keyword is surely slower, even I batch them is there a chance it will be quicker than comparing in memory?

Comment: I am not against sphinx, just don't know much about it - yet - would that be a case of saving the article, triggering sphinx to re-index then sending it a bunch of Multi-queries?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: For that I suggest you consult their wiki: http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php , Hope it has helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your code looks something like this:

```
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
    if(strpos($keyword, $articleText) != -1){
        $foundKeywords[] = $keyword;
    }
}
```

Something you may consider since the keywords array is so large and will continue to grow is to switch your processing to loop through the words in the text instead of the keywords array.  Something like this:

```
$textWords = explode(" ", $articleText);

foreach($textWords as $word){
    if( array_search($word, $keywords) && !array_search($word, $foundKeywords) ){
        $foundKeywords[] = $word;
    } 
}
```

Comment: more or less - but you might want to use word/non-word boundaries for splitting rather than spaces (see PCRE) and why not push it down to the database tier and implement a search engine while you're at it?

Comment: Note in your code that strpos returns boolean false if there are no occurences and not -1.

Comment: Sadly that method does not help, I tested and it actually takes nearly twice as long, also I think I didn't explain in my original post very well, but some of the tags are keyphrases, so more than one word which means splitting by word breaks misses a lot of them